# NVIDIA K-80 GPU does not run with Deep Learning Image Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-compute-engine

I have created a virtual machine in Google Compute us-east-1c region with the following specifications: n1-standard-2 (2 vCPU, 7.5 GB memory), 1 NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPU, boot disk: Deep Learning Image Tensorflow 1.10.1 m7 CUDA 9.2.

When I first logged in to the machine, it asked me to install the drivers and I agreed.  It gave me some warning messages which I did not save.

I tried to train a model written entirely in Keras with TF backend.

However, judging by the speed and CPU utilization (both similar to what it does on my laptop, slow and using almost all CPU available), GPU is not used.

This is also confirmed by the TF output:

> 2018-09-21 08:39:48.602158: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>   FMA

It did not mention any GPU.  (Thanks @Matias Valdenegro !)

In my model I did not relate to GPU with an understanding that TF takes care of it automatically.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: When you run TensorFlow code, it is printed in the terminal if its using the GPU or not, please include that information. Something like Found device 0 with properties: name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB major: 6 minor: 1 emoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7085

Comment: Please see my edit for this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my use of `requirements.txt`.

I created it on my laptop with `pip freeze`, uploaded it to the VM and used `pip` to install all the requirements.

In this way my `requirements.txt` included tensorflow.  As the result, pip installed the repository version that did not include GPU support, replacing pre-installed tensorflow with GPU support.

I was able to figure this out by repeating my steps and checking GPU per second suggestion of @Shintlor (thanks!) along the way.

I have created another VM and did not use requirements.txt; rather, I installed all the missing packages one by one.  After that my model trains now 20 times faster than on my laptop.

Answer (score 3):

To check if the GPU is in use you could check the output of

```
watch -n 0.5 nvidia-smi
```

while running your training and see if there are processes running.

You might also check the output of

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

and check for GPU usage.

Comment: Thanks for these tips to check for the presence of GPU.  I tried the second one and it responded: 

Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Device mapping: no known devices.

This confirms that the GPU is not running.

However, I did not ask how to check whether GPU is running - it was clear to me that it was not - but rather how to fix this.

So your answer is helpful but not to the point.